# Create view in sql server "names in each view or function must be unique"

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I'm trying to create view in sql server 2012, but I have this error message

```
Column names in each view or function must be unique. Column name 'Lastname' in view or function 'vFileImportDPERManagers' is specified more than once.
```

this is my view's code :

```
    GO



CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vFileImportDPERManagers]
    AS
SELECT M.*,
Managers.*

FROM            dbo.vFileImportDPERDebtors M WITH (NOLOCK)
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT
        M1.Man.value('@j11','varchar(20)') as ManagerKey,
        M1.Man.value('@j12','varchar(50)') as Lastname,
        M1.Man.value('@j13','varchar(50)') as Firstname,
        M1.Man.value('@j14','numeric') as ManagerFunctionId


    FROM DebtorXml.nodes('d1/d36/t324/j1') as M1(Man)
) as Managers
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the table dbo.vFileImportDPERDebtors will have a column called 'Lastname'. If you select all of your columns by name (i.e. expand * into names) you can alias one or both of the Lastname columns, `SELECT M.Lastname as Lastname1, Managers.Lastname as Lastname2...`. It's generally considered best-practice not to use 'SELECT *'.