# How to add COALESCE Statement to an existing View

Tags: sql, sql-server, alter, sql-view

This view is what I am working on. It works fine,
but I intend to add the COALESCE statement in the commented
out portion to this Script. Would anyone know how to write the
Script properly. When I combined them, there was an error.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[VW_Bzo_D]
AS WITH today AS
    (SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[Bz_DAYS]
    WHERE [DATE] = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
    ),
pd AS  (SELECT [DATE] AS REPORTING_PERIOD
        FROM dbo.Bz_DAYS
        WHERE DAY([DATE]) = 1
        )
SELECT  sp.*,
        rp.REPORTING_PERIOD,
        ac.DATE_ORDINAL AS CUSTOMER_ACCEPTANCE_ORDINAL,
        mv.DATE_ORDINAL AS CUSTOMER_MOVE_ORDINAL,
        today.DATE_ORDINAL TODAY_ORDINAL
/*sp.[CUSTOMER_MOVE], sp.[CUSTOMER_REQUESTED], sp.[LEASE_SIGNED_BY_GSA],
    sp.[SUBMITTED_TO_GSA], sp.[CUSTOMER_ACCEPTANCE],

COALESCE(sp.[CUSTOMER_MOVE], sp.[CUSTOMER_REQUESTED],       sp.[LEASE_SIGNED_BY_GSA],
    sp.[SUBMITTED_TO_GSA], sp.[CUSTOMER_ACCEPTANCE]
    ) AS REPORT_MONTH
*/
FROM dbo.Bzo_Den sp
```

The error is :

> Column names in each view or function must be unique. Column name
>   'CUSTOMER_MOVE' in view or function 'VW_Bzo_D' is specified more than
>   once.

Comment: 1) What error message you get? 2) Which RDBMS do you use?

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server Management Service. The error is : Column names in each view or function must be unique. Column name 'CUSTOMER_MOVE' in view or function 'VW_Bzo_D' is specified more than once.

Comment: Using `*` is bad habit, specify all needed columns by its names. Probably `sp.*` collides with commented `sp.[CUSTOMER_MOVE]`

Comment: SELECT sp.[TYPE],sp.[SIZE],sp.[AGENCY],sp.[IS_DELEGATED],sp.[IS_OSD],sp.[CUSTOMER_REQUESTED],
  sp.[RECEIVED_BY_PM],sp.[SUBMITTED_TO_GSA],sp.[LEASE_SIGNED_BY_GSA],
  sp.[CUSTOMER_ACCEPTANCE],sp.[CUSTOMER_MOVE],sp.[IMPORT_DATE],
  pd.REPORTING_PERIOD,                                                                           I specified each column and I am still getting the SAME error

Comment: post what the uncommented version of the code is? I believe I know what's the issue, but need to see what you're trying.

Comment: CREATE VIEW [dbo].[VW_Bzo_D]
AS WITH today AS
 (SELECT *
 FROM [dbo].[Bz_DAYS]
 WHERE [DATE] = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
 ),
pd AS  (SELECT [DATE] AS REPORTING_PERIOD
  FROM dbo.Bz_DAYS
  WHERE DAY([DATE]) = 1
  )
SELECT sp.*,
 rp.REPORTING_PERIOD,
        ac.DATE_ORDINAL AS CUSTOMER_ACCEPTANCE_ORDINAL,
        mv.DATE_ORDINAL AS CUSTOMER_MOVE_ORDINAL,
        today.DATE_ORDINAL TODAY_ORDINAL
 sp.[CUSTOMER_MOVE], sp.[CUSTOMER_REQUESTED],

Comment: sp.[LEASE_SIGNED_BY_GSA],
  sp.[SUBMITTED_TO_GSA], sp.[CUSTOMER_ACCEPTANCE],

COALESCE(sp.[CUSTOMER_MOVE], sp.[CUSTOMER_REQUESTED], sp.[LEASE_SIGNED_BY_GSA],
  sp.[SUBMITTED_TO_GSA], sp.[CUSTOMER_ACCEPTANCE]
  ) AS REPORT_MONTH
  
FROM dbo.Bzo_Den sp

Comment: You appear to be missing a comma after TODAY_ORDINAL and before sp.[CUSTOMER_MOVE]

Is that the cause?

Comment: I ran it with a comma - No difference. That is not the problem. Read the error code above

Comment: You're specifying `sp.*` and then later on `sp.[CUSTOMER_MOVE]`, which I believe is the cause of the error. Any of those `sp.` columns you specify after the initial `sp.*` will throw that error as you clean them up. I would say specify those that don't appear later rather than the * at the beginning, as @lad2025 mentioned above. If they all have to be at the beginning, then remove the re-state of them at the beginning of your commented out portion.

Comment: Look CLOSELY, I have already written the script WITHOUT sp.* - It still does not work.

Comment: Got it now! This is what WORKED for me  - I removed ALL the column names that were mentioned elsewhere in the Statement, and VOILA! It worked. Thank you to each one of you who contributed.

Comment: Glad you got it working but using * in a view is NOT going to do what you think it does. It does not dynamically go and look at the column names. If the underlying table changes you will NOT get new columns and if the columns change around you can end up with totally incorrect data. Do yourself a favor and name each column explicitly.

Comment: Thank you, Sean - that is what I did (named each column explicitly)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this will help but did you try aliasing the column names which is giving you trouble?

One of the other users had a similar problem and he tried aliasing. Please look at the link below

[Create view in sql server "names in each view or function must be unique"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190621/create-view-in-sql-server-names-in-each-view-or-function-must-be-unique)

Hope it helps.